# PHP and MYSQL sending emails to specific people from database

Tags: php, mysql, email

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result_verify_email) == 0) { // IF no previous user is   using this email .


        // Create a unique  activation code:
        $activation = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));


        $query_insert_user = "INSERT INTO `members` ( `Username`, `Email`, `Password`, `Activation`) VALUES ( '$name', '$Email', '$Password', '$activation')";


        $result_insert_user = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_insert_user);
        if (!$result_insert_user) {
            echo 'Query Failed ';
        }

        if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) { //If the Insert Query was successfull.


            // Send the email:
            $message = " To activate your account, please click on this link:\n\n";
            $message .= WEBSITE_URL . '/activate.php?email=' . urlencode($Email) . "&key=".$activation;
            mail($Email, 'Registration Confirmation', $message, 'From: ismaakeel@gmail.com');

            // Flush the buffered output.


            // Finish the page:
            echo '<div class="success">Thank you for
registering! A confirmation email
has been sent to '.$Email.' Please click on the Activation Link to Activate     your account </div>';


        } else { // If it did not run OK.
            echo '<div class="errormsgbox">You could not be registered due         to a system
error. We apologize for any
inconvenience.</div>';
        }

    } else { // The email address is not available.
        echo '<div class="errormsgbox" >That email
address has already been registered.
</div>';
    }
```

This is a sample of my code. I use a simple mail() to send an email, but it is not working. Can anybody point out any mistake? I am not getting error messages, but when I send an email, it is not working. I am not receiving the email! Please help!

Comment: localhost Just testing it

Comment: I have a SMTP in my other file

Comment: ini_set('SMPT', "smpt.gmail.com")

Answer (score 0):

First, check where you are hosting the script. Web servers on your PC usually are not configured with a mail server. If you are running the script on a shared hosting service, make sure that the service provides access tot he `mail()` function, and then contact support of your hosting service.

If you are running your script on a local server, you need to change setting in `php.ini` to set up your mail function to use SMTP; otherwise, you need to configure a mail server on your PC.

Also, if you use the `ini_set()` functions in PHP, make sure you are including these functions in the same script as your calls to the `mail` function,  because [this value is only set for the duration of the current scripts execution.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)